# 'Focus' as a reporting verb?

Tags: verbs

> The builders focused on dealing with the problems.

In this example, 'focus' is classed as a reporting verb. I'm afraid I don't understand this at all. My understanding is that reporting verbs are used when conveying ideas or speech.

To clarify: This has been migrated for me. I'm a native speaker.I was preparing a lesson, and found this resource. Just wanted to confirm that it's an error.Focus is not a reporting verb. Hey,I usually defer to Cambridge University haha.

Comment: "'focus' is classed as a reporting verb" By whom? Where did the example sentence come from? Is there any context?

Comment: It's not a reporting verb

Comment: https://www.cambridgeenglish.org/learning-english/activities-for-learners/c1g001-reporting-verbs

Comment: Focus: [to concentrate attention or effort](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/focus). It seems a stretch to call it a reporting verb, although if people focused on a topic they might discuss it or come to conclusions about it, and you could report the discussion or conclusions. Not sure if you're asking what a reporting verb is, or asking what *focus* means, or asking a more specific question about the exercise.